# Как определить какая реализация в лямбда-выражении до его исполнения?

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

Постигаю лямбда-выражения и возник вопрос: «возможно ли определить какая реализация в момент времени в лямбда-выражении?»
Пример ниже:

```
interface TestLambda{
    String exec();
}

public class Main {

    public static String meth1(){return "1";}
    public static String meth2(){return "2";}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestLambda l = ((new Random()).nextBoolean())?(Main::meth1):(Main::meth2);
        /* как определить что сейчас в переменой l, т.е. что выполниться при l.exec()  */
        System.out.println(l.exec());

    }
}
```

Comment: смысл как раз в том, что не надо определять какой там код.

Comment: но вы можете через рефлексию посмотреть, но это скажется на производительности.

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman, а можете простенький пример показать как в такой ситуации через рефлексию определить реализацию?

Comment: Вы хотите наперед узнать какой метод выполнится: `meth1` или `meth2`?

Comment: default locale, да, имено так

Comment: `Boolean b = (new Random()).nextBoolean(); System.out.println(b?"meth1":"meth2");`

Comment: Вы можете описать конкретную задачу зачем вам это понадобилось? Пока вопрос выглядит так "Я взял гвозди, потому, что их не надо закручивать как саморезы, подскажите как мне их забить отверткой?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В комментариях уже написали, что определение реализации интерфейса, тем более лямбда-выражения, противоречит назначению как интерфейсов, так и лямбда выражений.

Наверняка задачу для которой потребовался подобный механизм можно решить изменением логики, например:

- отделить логику определения нужного метода от вызова;
- вместо лямбда выражений генерировать объекты классов с заданным интерфейсом;
- оборачивать используемые классы добавляя по мере необходимости идентификацию 
  и вывод в логи.

Тем не менее, если будут использоваться только ссылки на методы, то может подойти решение ниже:

Если сделать интерфейс сериализуемым:

```
interface TestLambda extends Serializable {

    String exec();
}
```

, то будет работать такой метод:

```
private static String findMethodName(TestLambda setter) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    Class<?> cl = setter.getClass();
    Method m = cl.getDeclaredMethod("writeReplace");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    Object replacement = m.invoke(setter);
    SerializedLambda l = (SerializedLambda) replacement;
    return l.getImplClass() + "::" + l.getImplMethodName();
}
```

И он будет возвращать названия методов и классов:

```
TestLambda lambda = new Random().nextBoolean() ? Main::meth1 : Main::meth2;
System.out.println(findMethodName(lambda));
```

Работа метода основана на том, что:

- если целевой тип лямбды сериализуем, то и лямбда сериализуема;
- для сериализации лямбды создается анонимный тип, в котором определяется метод [`writeReplace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), который возвращает [`SerializedLambda`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html);
- используется ссылка на метод и сигнатуры полностью совпадают, вследствие чего `getImplClass` и `getImplMethodName` возвращают корректные значения (в любом более сложном случае будут возвращаться имена анонимных классов/методов).

Comment: Спасибо. Вы открыли для меня новые горизонты для изучения.